# Data cleaning: Remove 0 value from my dataset having a header and index_col

Tags: python, pandas, count, header, boolean

I have a dataset showing below.

[image]

What I would like to do is three things.
Step 1: AA to CC is an index, however, happy to keep in the dataset for the future purpose.
Step 2: Count 0 value to each row.
Step 3: If 0 is more than 20% in the row, which means more than 2 in this case because DD to MM is 10 columns, remove the row.
So I did a stupid way to achieve above three steps.

```
df = pd.read_csv("dataset.csv", header=None)
df_bool = (df == "0")
print(df_bool.sum(axis=1))
```

then I got an expected result showing below.

```
0 0
1 0
2 1
3 0
4 1
5 8
6 1
7 0
```

So removed the row #5 as I indicated below.

```
df2 = df.drop([5], axis=0)
print(df2)
```

This works well even this is not an elegant, kind of a stupid way to go though.
However, if I import my dataset as header=0, then this approach did not work at all.

```
df = pd.read_csv("dataset.csv", header=0)

0 0
1 0
2 0
3 0
4 0
5 0
6 0
7 0
```

How come this happens?
Also, if I would like to write a code with loop, count and drop functions, what does the code look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just continue using [`boolean_indexing`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

First we calculate number of columns and number of zeroes per row:

```
n_columns = len(df.columns)  # or df.shape[1]
zeroes = (df == "0").sum(axis=1)
```

We then select only rows that have less than 20 % zeroes.

```
proportion_zeroes = zeroes / n_columns
max_20 = proportion_zeroes < 0.20
df[max_20]  # This will contain only rows that have less than 20 % zeroes
```

One liner:

```
df[((df == "0").sum(axis=1) / len(df.columns)) < 0.2]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback.
It worked well even one liner as long as if I import my dataset as header=None.
Anyway, I appreciate it!!

Answer (score 0):

It would have been great if you could have posted how the dataframe looks in pandas rather than a picture of an excel file. However, constructing a dummy df

```
 df = pd.DataFrame({'index1':['a','b','c'],'index2':['b','g','f'],'index3':['w','q','z']
              ,'Col1':[0,1,0],'Col2':[1,1,0],'Col3':[1,1,1],'Col4':[2,2,0]})
```

Step1, assigning the index can be done using the .set_index() method as per below

`df.set_index(['index1','index2','index3'],inplace=True)`

instead of doing everything manually when it comes fo filtering out, you can use the return you got from `df_bool.sum(axis=1)` in the filtering of the dataframe as per below

```
df.loc[(df==0).sum(axis=1) / (df.shape[1])>0.6]
index1  index2  index3  Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4
c       f       z       0       0       1       0
```

and using that you can drop those rows, assuming 20% then you would use

`df = df.loc[(df==0).sum(axis=1) / (df.shape[1])<0.2]`

Ween it comes to the header issue it's a bit difficult to answer without seeing the what the file or dataframe looks like

Comment: Dear Pureluck, thank you very much for your comment and your kind effort. I did worked! For the header issued, give a second please, I will give it a try to post my data to this forum. Best.

Comment: Dear Pureluck, thank you again for your help. I have solved the header/no header issue. If headr=None, then, all columns have type string. However, if I pass a header, then columns DD to MM have type integer, indicating I had to changer code from (df == "0") to (df == 0). Anyway, thank you so much for thinking of my questions.